# Mediafoundation: Putting Videos together

Tags: video, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

my plan is to put 2 videos together.
For example. I have 2 input videos-streams (both h264/aac) with a resolution 640x360. 
I want to put them together to a new video with the resolution 
1280x360 and two audio tracks (optional).

Has anyone an idea how to start this with mediafoundation or if this is even possible?

Comment: It's possible but it would be difficult. If it's a one off task why not use ffmpeg? The former will take hours, the latter minutes.

Comment: How could that be done with FFMpeg, is there a command line parameter

Comment: Ok, for ffmpeg its simple, but there are some issues:
- No GPU usage
- Only one audio channel (i would like to have one for each tile)

So at the moment I would prefer using MF for decoding, manipulating and recoding.